# Advantages and disadvantages of writing trig functions with a factorized argument

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

We have this general way of writing general trigonometric functions as

$$T(x) = a\sin(b(x-c)) +d$$

which is nice because the amplitude $a$, phase shift $c$ and mid-line (damn, I forgot what it's called) $d$ are very easy to pick out just by looking at it.

However, in a lot of textbooks, I see it written as $$T(x) = a\sin(kx+c)+d$$ and I wonder what the advantages of this are? Sure, the amplitude and mid-line are just as easy to pick out, but the phase shift is now dependent on the ratio of $k$ and $c$.

Isn't it better to default to the first way of writing it?

Comment: Advantage vs disadvantage requires a purpose, ie what you are trying to achieve. One form could be better for some purposes, the other form may be better for other purposes.

Comment: @sammygerbil - Agreed. So I'm wondering what the purpose would be for the unfactorized form.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between the 2 forms is the 'phase offset'. In the 1st form this is measured in the same units as $x$. In the 2nd form it is measured in the units of angle (radians).

Which form is more 'advantageous' depends on whether it is more useful to you to express the phase in units of property $k$ or $x$ (eg wavelength/displacement, period/time) or in the dimensionless unit of radians.

Advantages of expressing 'phase' or 'phase shift' in radians include that (i) it is **universal** - you do not need to know wavelength or period to see whether the wave has reached a peak or trough; and (ii) it is **conventional** - it makes communication of ideas easier if everyone is using the same 'language' or definitions.

However within a particular narrow application, in which only one wavelength or period of wave is used, it might be more advantageous to express phase in metres or seconds because these can be measured more directly and are less abstract.